# Can I detect whether an UDP-socket or a connected UDP socket is used?

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, netstat

Can I detect whether a client application uses an UDP-socket or a **connected** UDP-socket?

If yes, how? If no, why?

Comment: What do you mean by connected UDP socket? UDP is a connectionless protocol.

Comment: And this "client application", are you talking about a random app probably on a remote machine or about your particular program?

Comment: From code, you can call `connect` on a UDP socket.  That enforces only traffic to/from the connection address is allowed (and all other packets get dropped) and allows you to use `send` instead of `sendto`, but the traffic is still UDP.   Maybe the `netstat` command will show something...

Comment: @Vovanrock2002: https://www.softlab.ntua.gr/facilities/documentation/unix/unix-socket-faq/unix-socket-faq-5.html#ss5.2 and yes I mean any random app on a remote machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment above, code call `connect` on a UDP socket. That enforces only traffic to/from the connection address is allowed (and all other packets get dropped) and allows you to use send instead of `sendto`, but the traffic is still UDP.

But you **can** use the `netstat` command from the command line to see if the datagram socket has a remote address association:

For example, imagine if the code did this:

```
// create a datagram socket that listens on port 12345
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
port = 12345;
addrLocal.sin_family = AF_INET;
addrLocal.sin_port = htons(port);
result = bind(sock, (sockaddr*)&addrLocal, sizeof(addrLocal));

// associate the socket only with packets arriving from 1.2.3.4:6666
addrRemote.sin_family = AF_INET;
addrRemote.sin_port = htons(6666);
addrRemote.sin_addr.s_addr = ipaddress;  // e.g. "1.2.3.4"
result = connect(sock, (sockaddr*)&addrRemote, sizeof(addrRemote));
```

A corresponding `netstat -a -u` will reveal the following:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-15:~$ netstat -u -a
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
udp        0      0 ip-10-0-0-15:12345      1.2.3.4:6666            ESTABLISHED
```

The presence of a value that isn't `*:*` in the `Foreign Address` column for the UDP socket will reveal if the socket has connection address associated with it.